# 2D-MUSIC algorithm for range-azimuth mapping in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, azimuth

I have complications implementing the range-azimuth with the 2D Music algorithm. I have used the URA-azimuth to find the reflected signal by the elevation angles over the signal. I want to plot the range-angle mapping to find the targets' distance along with the device. Below is my code. How can I find the range-azimuth code from my current code or any suggestions? : Here is my current code:

```
f1 = 17000;
f2 = 19000;
doa1 = [40;10];
doa2 = [-60;20];
thetas = 90*pi/180
p = -pi/2:pi/180:pi/2;
doa = [doa1 doa2];
fc = 18000;
c = physconst('LightSpeed')
lam = c/fc
fs = 48000;

array = phased.URA('Size',[15 12],'ElementSpacing',[lam/2 lam/2]);
array.Element.FrequencyRange = [18e5 23.0e5];

fileId = fopen('D:\signal123.mat');
signal1 = fileId;
%signal_reshape = reshape(signal,[],2)
x = collectPlaneWave(array,[signal1,signal1],doa,fc)
%noise = 0.1*(randn(size(x))+1i*randn(size(x)));

estimator = phased.MUSICEstimator2D('SensorArray',array,...
    'OperatingFrequency',fc,...
    'NumSignalsSource','Property',...
    'DOAOutputPort',true,'NumSignals',2,...
    'AzimuthScanAngles',-90:.5:90,...
    'ElevationScanAngles',-90:.5:90)
[~,doas] = estimator(x)

plotSpectrum(estimator);
```

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erw0p.png)